# Aggregate a data.table rolling join

Tags: r, data.table

I have two `data.table`s:

```
library(data.table) # 1.9.6

DT1 <- data.table(id = rep(c("a", "b"), c(3, 2)),
                  x  = c(6,12,15,37,41),
                  y  = 1)
DT1[]

DT2 <- data.table(id = rep(c("a", "b"), c(4, 5)),
                  x = c(2,7,11,15,27,30, 35, 38,40))
DT2[]
```

I would like to do a rolling join with the tables and update `DT2` by reference with the value of `y` from `DT1`. This almost does what I want:

```
DT2[DT1, y := y, on = c("id", "x"), roll = -Inf]
DT2[]
```

However, I noticed that after this operation

```
DT2[4]
```

has `y = 1`, whereas, if I do the rolling join either a) without row 2 of `DT1` OR without row 3 of `DT1` I always get the same result since in both cases, the y from DT1 is joined to row 4 in `DT2` - example:

```
DT2[, y:= NULL]
DT2[DT1[!2], y := y, on = c("id", "x"), roll = -Inf]
DT2[]
DT2[, y:= NULL]
DT2[DT1[!3], y := y, on = c("id", "x"), roll = -Inf]
DT2[]
```

What I would like to achieve as a result is

```
DT2[4, y := 2][]
```

i.e. where the join leads to multiple values in a "cell", I want the total / aggregate value. Is this possible using `data.table`'s rolling join and update-by-reference functionality?

Comment: The newest stable version is 1.10.0 JFY

Comment: @DavidArenburg updating packages is not trivial in production environmemts especilly with potentially breaking changes.

Comment: @docendodiscimus you are probably aware, but still worth to mention... you can create new dir and use it as library path, install latest version there, and load it explicitly from that library only when you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ugly workaround is to build the aggregate table and then merge a second time on that:

```
agg = DT2[DT1, on=.(id, x), roll=-Inf, .(id, x = x.x, y = i.y)][, sum(y), by=.(id, x)]

DT2[agg, on=.(id, x), roll=-Inf, y := i.V1 ]
```

[There's an open FR](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/733) that I think would allow `DT2[DT1, on=.(id,x), y := sum(i.y), by=x.x]`.

Comment: Thanks, as you say it's a workaround - I'm still hoping someone comes along with a more direct way.